# how to use local font awesome?

Tags: css, font-awesome

I download the font awesome library to my local directory, and put them as following directory:

```
index.html
css/font-aswesome.min.css
font/fontawesome-webfont.xxx
```

And here is my index.html.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Font-Awesome</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-lg"></i> fa-lg
</body>
</html>
```

and open index.html, there is no font awesome css style implement here. But after I replace to use CDN link to replace the local href, everything works fine.
Anyone can help me to how to make font-awesome use local copy?

Comment: are you running the file on an http-server? If the URL is `file://`, then it won't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Font-Awesome css not working locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28585575/font-awesome-css-not-working-locally)

Answer (score 0):

I just followed the instructions on the offical fontawesome documentation [Set up Fontawesome Locally](https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/setup/host-yourself/webfonts)

1. First download the source from *https://fontawesome.com/download*
2. Next, extract the file and copy the folders you need in your project
3. (if you are working with web, you must copy the */css* folder and */webfonts* folder and put it into your project's */assets/fontawesome* folder)

**NOTE:** */webfonts* folder is important to make sure it works locally so do not forget to include it in */assets/fontawesome* directory
4. lastly source it in the  i recommend using *all.min.css* so that you only need to source one file

```html
<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/all.min.css">

</head>
```

**NOTE:** But if you only need a certain type of fontawesome *(e.g solid, sharp,regular ...)* you need to include fontawesome.css and the type of design you prefer:

```html
<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/fontawesome/css/fontawesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/fontawesome/css/solid.css">

</head>
```

Answer (score -1):

follow the following steps:

```
 1. Download the font-awesome package from their website.
 2. Extract the package where you will find the `font-awesome.css` file.
 3. Copy this file to your `CSS` directory.
 4. Copy all the fonts files from the extracted font-awesome package to your fonts folder.
 5. Finally, add the `font-awesome.css` to your HTML page by giving the respective location of the CSS file.
```

Answer (score -1):

How to use local font awesome?
As of writing this answer the latest version of Font Awesome is 5.15.4

- Download the free version of Font Awesome from [here](https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/fontawesome-free-5.15.4-web.zip)
- Extract the downloaded package
- Copy the entire /webfonts folder and the /css/all.css into your project’s static assets directory.
- Add a reference to the copied /css/all.css file like below code into the `<head>` element of each template or page that you want to use Font Awesome on.

`<link href="/your-path-to-fontawesome/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">`

- Now you can start using the font awesome icons locally in your project `<i class="fas fa-user"></i>`